# Folder Filler with Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a program that creates a certain amount of files inside a folder. The number of files to create works perfectly but when I add the option to input the size of the files it completely fails.

This is my actual code:

```
@echo off
set counter = 1
set loopTime = 0
cls
set /p filesNumber=files: 
set /p fileSize=file size: 

:loop
set /a counter = counter + 1
type nul > ping%counter%
if "%fileSize%" != "0" goto insertFileSize
:continue
set /a loopTime = loopTime + 1
if "%loopTime%" == "%filesNumber%" goto end
goto loop

:insertFileSize
set insertFileSizeLoopTime = 0
:insertFileSizeTempFunc
echo 0 >> ping%counter%
set /a insertFileSizeLoopTime = insertFileSizeLoopTime + 1
if "%insertFileSizeLoopTime%" == "fileSize" goto continue
goto inserFileSizeTempFunc

:end
cls
echo %filesNumber% files created successfully.
pause
```

When I run it with `filesNumber = 10` and `fileSize = 10`, it creates a file called `ping1`, which is right, but only one and with 0 bytes.

I was expecting 10 files `[ping1, ping2, ..., ping10]` and each one with 10 bytes.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Enter `fsutil file createnew` on command line and examine the output.

Comment: Don't put spaces around `=` in `set` statements. Batch allows spaces in variable names, so you've created variables called `%counter %`, `%loopTime %`, etc.

Comment: `!=` is invalid syntax. You need `neq `

Comment: Every `echo 0 >>` increases the size by 4, a 0, a space and CR and LF.